# Custom Function that will have data moved to multiple sheets from corresponding button click

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am attempting to be able to click start and stop buttons on the main page and have start and stop timestamps transferred to the corresponding sheet in the spreadsheet.  I have programmed the "Paper Change" and "Refill" start and stop buttons but they are both outputting to the "Paper Change" tab. 
Here is the code for the Refill start and stop buttons:

---

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Refills");


function startTimeRefill() {
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 0, 2).setValue(new Date());

}

function stopTimeRefill() {
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(new Date());
}
```

---

Here is the code I am using for the Paper Change button:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PaperChange");


function startTimePaperChange() {
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 0, 2).setValue(new Date());
}


function stopTimePaperChange() {
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared variables for Sheet Names however all your output is directed to one sheet ("Paper Change") and not to both sheets as one might expect.

The cause of this is that the variable `ss` has been declared twice (once as `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Refills");` and again as `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PaperChange");`), and they exist outside the respective functions. In this situation where a variable is used twice, JavaScript moves that declaration to the top of the scope" - the effect is that the "Paper Change" sheet is the var value for both functions, and this explains your problem.

The most simple solution is to change the name of one of the `ss` variables so that the variable name is only used once. For instance:
`var refills = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Refills");`

An alternative is to change the scope of the `var ss` declarations by moving them into the function.

**Reading**

[Declaring a Javascript variable twice in same scope-Is it an issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21727020/1330560)
[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/1330560): a much more detailed discussion here.